# from contact form to sendemail MVC5

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Im having some contact form and I have in a HomeController method SendMessage, also in my form I have hidden success and error div.
How to call sendmessage, but to stay on the same page?

Comment: Use an [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) call

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Igor, use an ajax call to hit your controller/method.
Here is an example -

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#sendMail').click(function () {
            $("#sendMail").empty();
            $("#sendMail").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#sendMail").append('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>Please wait...');
            $.ajax
            ({
                url: '@Url.Action("SendMail", "ControllerName")',
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'application/json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'name': $('#txtName').val(), 'email': $('#txtEmail').val(), 'message': $('#txtMessage').val() }),

                success: function (result) {
                    $("#sendMail").empty();
                    $("#sendMail").append('Send Message');
                    $("#sendMail").attr("disabled", false);                       
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    $("#sendMail").empty();
                    $("#sendMail").append('Send Message');
                    $("#sendMail").attr("disabled", false);

                }
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

In above javascript function -

When user clicks on button with text 'Send Mail' and id = sendMail, I disabled the button so the user won't click it multiple times and change the text of button to 'Please wait' and add a spinner for dramatic effect. I also send email of the user and name and message with the ajax call. On ajax success, I show a toaster with success message and remove the spinner and please wait text from the button and set 'Send Mail' text again.

I removed toaster javascript part in case you want to use other notification method. Good luck.